# How can I override a Paragraphs field & bundle output with custom template in a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

**Backstory**

I have created multiple Paragraph bundles. My goal is to have absolute control over the output of these bundles (1) as well as the output of the containing field (2) in a scalable way (for ease of future bundle addition -- there may be 30+ bundles in the future).

**Where I'm at**

I've created a theme suggestion using `HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` to override the bundles' output. This allowed me to create custom twig templates for each bundle.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 *
 * Register a theme for each paragraph type
 *
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  $theme_templates  = [];
  $paragraph_types  = MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types();

  // Register custom Paragraph bundle templates
  foreach ($paragraph_types as $paragraph_type){
    $theme_templates['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $paragraph_type] = [
      'base hook' => 'paragraph'
    ];
  }

  // Register custom Paragraph bundle template fallback
  $theme_templates['paragraph__MYMODULE'] = [
    'base hook' => 'paragraph'
  ];

  // Register custom Paragraph field wrapper
  // $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
  // $theme_templates['paragraph__MYMODULE__field_wrapper'] = [
  //   'base hook' => 'field',
  //   'template' => 'paragraph--MYMODULE--field-wrapper',
  //   'path' => $module_path . '/templates'
  //  ];

  return $theme_templates;
}

/**
 * Implements HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $field = $variables['element']['#field_name'];

  if( $field == 'field_content_modules' ) {
    $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__field_wrapper';
  }
}


/**
 * Implements HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_paragraph_alter(&$suggestions, $variables){
  $entity              = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $type                = $entity->getType();

  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE';
  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type;
  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $module_path      = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
  $template_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.html.twig', $module_path);
  $paragraph_types  = MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types();

  // 1. Loop through the paragraph types
  // 2. Check if each paragraph exists in the `$template_objects` array
  // 3. If it doesn't exist, remove it from the registry so we don't get any errors
  // 4. If it does exist, set actual path to template
  foreach ($paragraph_types as $type){
    $template = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type;
    if(!isset($template_objects[$template])){
      unset($theme_registry['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type]);
    } else {
      $theme_registry['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type]['path'] = $template_objects[$template]['path'];
    }
  }
}


/**
 * Helper function to get a list of paragraph types by machine name
 *
 * @return array
 */
function MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types(){
  $paragraph_bundles = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('paragraph');
  return array_keys($paragraph_bundles);
}
```

So part 1 is done.

Part 2 is controlling the Paragraph field (not bundle) container HTML. This should be just a plain field template override. I've added a file:

```
/modules/custom/MYMODULE/templates/paragraph--MYMODULE--field-wrapper.html.twig
```

...and dropped in the contents of field.html.twig.
When I uncomment the `hook_theme` code above ("Register custom Paragraph field wrapper"), I get this error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() must be of the type array, null
>   given, called in
>   /Users/phil/Sites/glades/www/modules/contrib/paragraphs/paragraphs.module
>   on line 238 and defined in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()
>   (line 71 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong with the field template override?

Most of this was inspired by a comment by jeremypeter here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2499827#comment-12159763

Comment: For part 2, you can't register a field template with the name `paragraph--`, because the naming convention for templates is, that the template name starts with the base hook. Use `field--paragraph--MYMODULE--...` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per 4k4's comment to the original post, it was a naming convention issue as seen here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

In the *hook_theme* and *hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter* function above, I changed:

```
paragraph__contentmodules__field_wrapper
```

to:

```
field__paragraph__contentmodules__field_wrapper
```

Working code:

```
<?php


/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 *
 * Register a theme for each paragraph type
 *
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  $theme_templates  = [];
  $paragraph_types  = MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types();

  // Register custom Paragraph bundle templates
  foreach ($paragraph_types as $paragraph_type){
    $theme_templates['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $paragraph_type] = [
      'base hook' => 'paragraph'
    ];
  }

  // Register custom Paragraph bundle template fallback
  $theme_templates['paragraph__MYMODULE'] = [
    'base hook' => 'paragraph'
  ];

  // Register custom Paragraph field wrapper
  $theme_templates['field__paragraph__MYMODULE__field_wrapper'] = [
    'base hook' => 'field',
  ];

  return $theme_templates;
}

/**
 * Implements HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $field = $variables['element']['#field_name'];

  if( $field == 'field_content_modules' ) {
    $suggestions[] = 'field__paragraph__MYMODULE__field_wrapper';
  }
}


/**
 * Implements HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_paragraph_alter(&$suggestions, $variables){
  $entity              = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $type                = $entity->getType();

  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE';
  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type;
  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $module_path      = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
  $template_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.html.twig', $module_path);
  $paragraph_types  = MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types();

  // 1. Loop through the paragraph types
  // 2. Check if each paragraph exists in the `$template_objects` array
  // 3. If it doesn't exist, remove it from the registry so we don't get any errors
  // 4. If it does exist, set actual path to template
  foreach ($paragraph_types as $type){
    $template = 'paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type;
    if(!isset($template_objects[$template])){
      unset($theme_registry['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type]);
    } else {
      $theme_registry['paragraph__MYMODULE__' . $type]['path'] = $template_objects[$template]['path'];
    }
  }
}


/**
 * Helper function to get a list of paragraph types by machine name
 *
 * @return array
 */
function MYMODULE_get_paragraph_types(){
  $paragraph_bundles = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('paragraph');
  return array_keys($paragraph_bundles);
}
```